# dropdown attribute is not saving in database

Tags: database, product-attribute, custom-attributes, multi-vendor

we are using magento multi vendor site.

In frontend we gave an option for vendor update product attributes

we are using following code to update custom attribute "local" .its working fine.

```
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner : Textfield
```

**phtml**

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('local');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "local_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "local[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>
<?php endif; ?>


<input type="hidden" name="localcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="localcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getLocal(); ?>" /> 

<p id="updatedlocal_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>
<button id="local_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>

<button id="local_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>
```

**JS**

```
function hideResetLocal(product_id,localold) { 

var qtyId='#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#localcurr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#local_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#local_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valuelocal="#valuelocal_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#local_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valuelocal).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currlocal).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}



function showFieldLocal(product_id)
        {

            var qtyId='#local_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#local_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var valuelocal="#valuelocal_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#local_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#local_reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
            $wk_jq(valuelocal).hide();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }




function updateFieldLocal(product_id) 
{ 
var localId = '#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#localcurr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedlocal_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldLocal/')?>'; 
$local = $wk_jq(localId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currlocal).val($local); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 

parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
//parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function updateFieldLocalAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_local = $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        

        $product->setLocal($upd_local);

        $product->save();

        echo $local = $product->getLocal();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

In the same way, we are using following code to update custom attribute : "cod".
but its not saving in database.

```
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner : Dropdown
```

**phtml**

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('cod');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "cod_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"  name= "cod[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>
<?php endif; ?>


<input type="hidden" name="codcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="codcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getCod(); ?>" /> 

<p id="updatedcod_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>
<button id="cod_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="update" onclick="updateFieldCod('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>

<button id="cod_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetCod('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>
```

**JS**

```
function hideResetCod(product_id,codold) { 

var qtyId='#cod_'+ product_id; 
var currcod='#codcurr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#cod_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#cod_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valuecod="#valuecod_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#cod_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valuecod).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currcod).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}



function showFieldCod(product_id)
        {

            var qtyId='#cod_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#cod_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var valuecod="#valuecod_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#cod_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#cod_reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();
            $wk_jq(valuecod).hide();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }




function updateFieldCod(product_id) 
{ 
var codId = '#cod_'+ product_id; 
var currcod='#codcurr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedcod_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldCod/')?>'; 
$cod = $wk_jq(codId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currcod).val($cod); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 

parameters: {id: product_id, cod: $cod}, 
//parameters: {id: product_id, cod: $cod}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function updateFieldCodAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_cod = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cod');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        

        $product->setCod($upd_cod);

        $product->save();

        echo $cod = $product->getCod();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

Comment: `Dropdown` change it to `textfield` because for dropdown you have to set `option` in backend too and you can set only those values.

Comment: i will check how it will work for our feature.

Comment: add option in attribute in backend and select from those option will worked for you if you want to add dropdown.

Comment: we are already using that attribute in live site and thousands of products are already assigned to that drop down attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "cod_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"  name= "cod[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>
```

with

```
<select  id = "cod_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"  name= "cod[]" ">

<option value="0" <?php if($products->getCod()==0) { echo "selected";} ?>>No</option>
<option value="1"<?php if($products->getCod()==1) { echo "selected";} ?>>Yes</option>


 </select>
```

Comment: i am getting this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in

Comment: update it is yes and not option in backend?

Comment: only "yes" and "no" option is there in backend

Comment: updated the answer..

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: check extra added } in your code

Comment: dropdown is working, but once i refresh the page, values are not saving in database.

Comment: refresh the cache and reindex

Comment: i will try that....

Comment: updated the answer try that

Comment: still not saving in database.

Comment: you didn't change the latest answer changes.

Comment: i changed your updated code. even cache is disabled.

Comment: there was spelling mistake 'value' add this in option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33575/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: code is working fine i check and it changing the value update the answer update you code and check

Comment: i tried it , but stil its displaying NO. here extension team did't gave any dropdown values when creating attribute.